# How to replace the id of a get paramete with his name instead in PHP?

Tags: php, routes

Hello Stackoverflow community, I'm new using PHP and I have been trying to figure out how to make urls friendly to the user. This is what a I need to do:

Go from this:

**http://localhost/myproject/categories/1**

To this:

**http://localhost/myproject/categories/{name of the category}**

I currently using a simple Router class to handle my website entry point:

```
<?php

namespace CMS;

class Router
{
    private array $handlers;
    private $notFoundHandler;
    private const METHOD_POST = 'POST';
    private const METHOD_GET = 'GET';

    public function get( string $path, $handler ): void
    {
        $this->addHandler(self::METHOD_GET, $path , $handler);
    }

    public function post( string $path, $handler ): void
    {
        $this->addHandler(self::METHOD_POST, $path , $handler);
    }

    public function addHandler( string $method, string $path, $handler ): void
    {
        $this->handlers[$method . $path] = [
            'path' => $path,
            'method' => $method,
            'handler' => $handler
        ];
    }

    public function addNotFoundHandler($handler):void
    {
        $this->notFoundHandler = $handler;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $requestUri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $requestPath = $requestUri['path'];
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        $callback = null;
        foreach ($this->handlers as $handler){
            if($handler['path'] === $requestPath && $method === $handler['method']){
                $callback = $handler['handler'];
            }
        }

        if ( is_string($callback) ){
            $parts = explode('::', $callback);
            if ( is_array($parts) ){
                $className = array_shift($parts);
                $handler = new $className;

                $method = array_shift($parts);
                $callback = [$handler, $method];
            }
        }


        if (!$callback) {
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            if ( !empty($this->notFoundHandler) ) {
                $callback = $this->notFoundHandler;
            }
        }

        call_user_func_array($callback, [
            array_merge($_GET, $_POST)
        ]);

    }
}
```

An example of usage:

```
$router = new Router();

$router->get('/', function () {
    
    echo "<a href='/categories?id=1'>Click Here</a>"; //Entry Test
});

$router->get('/categories', function ( array $params) {
    echo 'Categories Page';
    echo '<h1> Hello' . $params['id'] . '</h1>'; //This shows the id of the category
});
```

Please I need help:(, thank you!!

Comment: There're a lot of php router libraries in GitHub. Install one of those and explore the source code. I'm sure you'll figure out how they're actually work under the hood.

Comment: Yes  , I found a library calls Simple PHP Router and it works for me, thank you for your comment anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution to my problem , I´m actually using a library calls Simple Router PHP. Here is the link:
[Simple-PHP-Router](https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router)

It has good documentation for any router feature that you need. Have nice day.